# getUser() always return 0 in Codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I started to create a small application using codeigniter framework 
and i have dowloaded Facebook connect from github after creating my application inside facebook, at this moment all  work alright my only problem is getUser() always return 0

i have create a facebook.php inside `application/config/`
alse i have extracting `facebook.php & base_facebook.php` inside `application/libraries/`

this is my code

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    private $data = array();



    public function index() {
        $this->data['loginUrl'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl();
        $this->data['userId'] = $this->facebook->getUser();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $this->data);
    }

}
```

in autoload 
i have :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','facebook');
```

so why `getUser()` return 0 and how can i fix this problem 
thx

Answer (score 3):

on `base_facebook.php`, find the `makeRequest()` method, and, inside the function, find this line:

```
$opts = self::$CURL_OPTS;
```

Immediately following it, add:

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
```

or read from [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/)

Answer (score 0):

It does this, sometimes. I've never worked out why, but there is a simple solution that I now always follow.

As opposed to asking for getUser, ask for api(/me) wrapped in a try catch block. If this fails, user is not logged in/token is invalid. If it works the user is logged in, and you get the user id from the resultant array.

You're probably saving a call, as you'll ask for /me anyway. Just remember the try catch for error trapping!

Comment: i have a bug when i use
<code>
Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:\wamp\www\project\application\libraries/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt CApath: none thrown in C:\wamp\www\project\application\libraries\base_facebook.php on line 967
</code>

Comment: In which case, different issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994059/facebook-application-development-using-php-sdk may help? You'll need to edit base_facebook.php to add the curl options in the makerequest() function