# Uncaught CurlException: 77 : error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I keep getting this same error. I just installed the SSL and no luck. I have checked out all the other posts but none of the solutions seemed to work for me.

Does anyone know what should I be doing ?

> Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 77: error setting certificate
>   verify locations: CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath:
>   none thrown in
>   /home/acmesoft/public_html/Oddsmaker/php_sdk/base_facebook.php on line
>   977

```
if ($result === false) {
  $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
    'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
    'error' => array(
    'message' => curl_error($ch),
    'type' => 'CurlException',
    ),
  ));
  curl_close($ch);
  throw $e;
}
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

Comment: Looks duplicate, try that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994059/facebook-application-development-using-php-sdk

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same error with you and this problem was solved, I just put this 2 lines

```
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
```

after your facebook apps definition

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
  'cookie' => true,
  'perms' => 'publish_stream,read_stream,email',
  'domain' => 'example.com'
))
```

Comment: This appeared for newly downloaded facebook php sdk like todays date. i used a copy of a previous download may be like 4 months back and did not get such errors... anyway. your workaround worked well for me.

Comment: Be careful with this answer; see patriot's answer below.  This a bad answer because it exposes your app to man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks.

Answer (score 12):

Riyanto Wibowo's response is dangerous because you're essentially turning off SSL. Be wary of taking that route. From a [comment on the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#110457):

> Please everyone, stop setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false or 0. If your PHP installation doesn't have an up-to-date CA root certificate bundle, download the one at the curl website and save it on your server:
>
> http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
>
> Then set a path to it in your php.ini file, e.g. on Windows:
>
> curl.cainfo=c:\php\cacert.pem
>
> Turning off CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER allows man in the middle (MITM) attacks, which you don't want!

I would have posted this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Better to dangerously have the damn thing work, then not have it work. People having to do this crap to break through the functioning-resistance is the fault of curl.haxx.se (or whoever made it), not themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt in the same folder as base_facebook.php. You can get it here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt