# Curl certificate error after php7.2-curl install

Tags: php, curl, debian

I was using a cacert.pem to use Google Admanager API
i wanted in a php file to use curl_init function. It was undefined so after some researches i tried to install it using `apt-get install php7.2-curl` command

After this I get this error
`cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /etc/php/7.2/cacert.pem CApath: /etc/ssl/certs (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

how can I fix it ?
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught CurlException: 77 : error setting certificate verify locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149308/uncaught-curlexception-77-error-setting-certificate-verify-locations)

Comment: do not disable the check, don't follow the accepted answer to that ^

Comment: does this file actually exist? `/etc/php/7.2/cacert.pem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the solution

I don't know why but the install changed the access rights of cacert.pem file so my web server wasn't able to use it.