# getUser() always return 0 though I logged in[Facebook-PHP-SDK]

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I read lots of questions which are related to my problem. However, I can't resolve it. The `getUser()` from `Facebook-php-sdk` always return 0 though I logged in. From my log:

```
Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information
```

I added "`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE`" to `BaseFacebook::$CURL_OPTS`. However, it's not working.

My code:

```
<?php

try {
            $facebook = new Social\Facebook ();
            $user_fb_id = $facebook->getUser();

            if ($user_fb_id) {

                //do something
            } else {
                $params = array(
                        'scope' => 'email, user_activities, read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_likes',
                        //'display' => 'touch',
                        'redirect_uri' => Uri::base(false) . 'userjob/login?url=' . $url
                );
                $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
                Response::redirect($login_url);
            }
        } 
catch (Exception $e) {

            echo "Error";
            echo $e->getMessage();
            die();
   }
```

By the way, I use `PHP5.3.2 (MAMP 1.9, MAC OS 10.7.5)`, the above code working fine on the other computers and working on the localhost to connect with Facebook. However, It's failed on my computer.

```
Update: (Solved)
```

Thank you all for helping me!
The problem is my hosts file. I clear some old IPs which are related to Facebook and it's working!

Comment: Is this an iframe app? like a page tab?

Comment: @Fabio Antunes: I just create a website which allows login and get user's info through Facebook.

Comment: And you're saying that it works well on others computers?

Comment: well that's a bit vague, are you working on a localhost?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532721/facebook-development-in-localhost/7493806#7493806

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it's still not working!

Comment: The problem is my hosts file. I clear some old IPs which are related to Facebook and it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the accepted answer here: [Facebook application development using PHP SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994059/facebook-application-development-using-php-sdk)

It seems like you're missing the FB certificate file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I had FB certificate fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt file

Comment: And you also set the $CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] and 
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] variables?

Comment: Yes, I did it but it's not working!